# Как сделать подсказку в input поле с подчеркиванием оставшегося кол-ва символов? (пример внутри)

Tags: jquery, input

https://lk.platon.ru/registration если выбрать юр. лиц, то на кор.счете, инн и прочем при выборе поля появляется подчеркивание, которое подсказывает сколько символов можно ввести. Как такое реализовать? Спасибо

Comment: https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput   посмотреть demo: http://www.jqueryrain.com/?PArDsxzR

Comment: отлично! Спасибо!

Comment: Все работает...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.